# PKAddPaymentPassViewController is nil

Tags: swift, xcode9, applepay, wallet

i have added merchent provisioning profile into app.

```
if (!PKAddPaymentPassViewController.canAddPaymentPass()){
        print("not enabled")
    }
    let config = PKAddPaymentPassRequestConfiguration.init(encryptionScheme: PKEncryptionScheme.ECC_V2)

    guard let addPaymentPassVC = PKAddPaymentPassViewController.init(requestConfiguration: config!, delegate: self) else { return }

    self.present(addPaymentPassVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

here is my code but  addPaymentPassVC is always nil and i'm getting message "missing entitlement: com.apple.developer.payment-pass-provisioning"

Also i have tryed to add this key com.apple.developer.payment-pass-provisioning
into entitlement file  and in this case i'm getting an error "...ProvisioningProfile" doesn't include the com.apple.developer.payment-pass-provisioning entitlement.

Answer (score 4):

As per your comment, it seems you don't have the correct entitlement to add passes to Wallet. The entitlement, `com.apple.developer.payment-pass-provisioning`, requires special permission from Apple to use in your app. Apple suggests contacting `apple-pay-inquiries@apple.com` for more information about this.

After getting permission from Apple, or if you already had permission, add the following key to your Entitlements file:

```
<key>com.apple.developer.payment-pass-provisioning</key>
<true/>
```

**Note:** Unfortunately, it seems as if it's not possible to test this without the special entitlement, as stated by Apple: `Your app must include this entitlement before this class can be instantiated.`

**Source:** https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkaddpaymentpassviewcontroller

Comment: So i can't see the PKAddPaymentPassViewController during my development without apple special permission?

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that's not possible. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: i thing there will be some sandbox for development. But still can't find the way